# How to access http://localhost/project through browser on any computer connected through VPN?

Tags: php, wamp, vpn, remote-desktop, rdp

Here is the scenario:

- I have connected over a VPN.
- I have RDP Server access for some IP say 13.xxx.xxx.xxx and connected it through Remote Desktop Connection on windows.
- On RDP Server, I have created a "test" project in wamp and can access it in the browser using http://localhost/test/. (Note: URL doesn't matter I just want the "test" project should be accessible).
- Now I want it to be accessible through my client's browser. The client can connect to the VPN but not allowed to connect the RDP server.

Thanks!

Comment: Localhost is by definition local. If your client is connected on the VPN he needs to enter the IP of the server instead of "localhost". Make sure all ports are correctly opened/forwarded if required.

Comment: @NoahBoegli Thanks for the suggestion, Right now I am trying to point the IP address using IIS.